# SQL trigger for expiration date

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, ddl

I have a table with the columns `expiration_date` and `isExpired`. I want to create a trigger to set the column `isExpired` to 1 if the column `expiration_date` passes the current date.

I have no experience with triggers.

Comment: You can use a computed column for this.

Comment: Ok. I have no idea what that is either. @MartinSmith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin Smith suggested in the comments, a trigger probably isn't the best approach here. Instead, you could use a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx), which is, in a nutshell, a column that has its value calculated ("computed") by  some other columns in the table.

In your case:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    col1 VARCHAR(10),
    col2 VARCHAR(20),
    expiration_date DATE,
    is_expired AS CASE WHEN expiration_date > GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mureinik. But there was an error after executing the query: "ALTER TABLE tblInventory ADD isExpired as EXPR_DATE > GETDATE()"

Error: Incorrect syntax near '>'.